# PHPCR Jackalope / Jackrabbit performance and compatibility (Symfony CMF)

Tags: jackrabbit, odm, symfony-cmf, doctrine-phpcr

Anticipating possible future issues, I decided to use Java-based Jackrabbit implementation (since it's the system with the highest performance according to the Symfony CMF docs) for the storage purposes. For the portal I'm developing I use at the moment Symfony CMF with PHPCR content repository feature + some related tables in a standard RDBMS (MySQL).

Unfortunetely I have a very little knowledge and almost none practical experience on content repository systems. So here's my question:

**When using `Jackrabbit` with `PHPCR-ODM` from within Symfony CMF app, am I able to access the stored content (being Document objects as seeing from `PHPCR-ODM`) from other solutions than PHPCR-ODM - say, from Java Spring app?**

**In other words, if I wanted at some stage switch to Java, and not touching the storage (Jackrabbit / MySQL), but just creating Java equivalent Documents, would I able to do this? Or I need to do some more work like exporting the database, and then make some work with importing it again to e.g. mentioned Java based solution?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can access the content from java without having to change the content. we even did a proof of concept to read data from Magnolia and Adobe CQ via PHPCR ODM.

Comment: Great news for us - thanks. No many reasons for using Doctrine's PHPCR solution left, I guess?